# Computing a 2 variable integral - switching the order of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to compute this integral:

$$\int_0^1 dy \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} e^{\frac{y}{x}} dx$$

Because we have not learn how to compute $\int e^{a}{x} dx$ (because it has something with gamma function etc..) it makes me think only of one option and is to flip the $dx \Leftrightarrow dy$

$\sqrt{y} = x \Rightarrow  y = x^2$

and thus $$ \int_0^1 dx \int_{x^2}^1 e^{\frac{y}{x}}dy = \int_0^1 dx (\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{1}{x}} - \frac{1}{x}e^x)$$

Which again leads me to this gamma function.. ($\Gamma$...) and we don't know how to work with it (not in our syllabus)

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were correct to interchange the order of integration.

Note that the region of integration spans from $\sqrt y\le x\le 1$ with $y\in [0,1]$.  This is the same region as the region $0\le y\le x^2$ with $x\in [0,1]$.  Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt y}^1 e^{y/x}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2} e^{y/x}\,dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(xe^x-x\right)\,dx
\end{align}$$

And now you can wrap this up.

Comment: You're welcome.  My plasure.